# Unability of opening documents in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: 14.04, wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office, microsoft-word

I am not able to open certain documents in Microsoft Word 2010. When I double click on the document there is a program error displayed saying

> The program DW20.EXE has encountered a serious problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.

And later PlayOnLinux opens saying

```
Error in POL_Wine
Wine seems to have crashed
If your program is running, just ignore this message
```

Comment: I would suggest you stop using wine/playonlinux and microsoft products. Do you absolutely need Microsoft Word? Have you tried Libreoffice?

Answer (score 5):

Configure PlayOnLinux to use wine 1.7.33 instead of 1.7.22 for Office 2010. That should fix it.

See also: [Wine forum: "DW20.exe error trying to run Office 2010"](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=23136)

Answer (score -1):

You must install msxml6 dll and set the enviroment to 32 bits.

However, if you must install office 2010 from zero:

Install:
   https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/playonlinux/
and:
   https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine1.4/

Then, using playonlinux, you must install office 2010.

Then select Microsoft Word  2010, select configuration (left menu) , configure wine -> libraries -> add msxml6 . Then return to Microsoft Word 2010 config (playubuntu)  add the msxml6 lib from the libraries tab.

Thats it, worked for me. Upvotes please, this is the answer, i got the same error.

Comment: using playubuntu: Install office , select word , select configuration (left menu) , configure wine -> libraries -> add msxml6 . The in cofiguration (playubuntu) add the msxml6 lib . Thats it, worked for me.

Comment: Please explain, how to do that (see [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer)).

Comment: PlayUbuntu hasn't been PlayUbuntu for years; it's http://www.playdeb.net  and please include explicit instructions on how to install it.

Comment: Thats not the question, the user already installed this stufs. However you are right the app is playOnLinux.